# Sharing private methods across files in JavaScript Module Pattern design

Tags: javascript, package, private, module-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

I'm creating a JavaScript library and I'm trying to split its functionality across two files.

Here's a simplified summary of what I have right now, in a file named *main.js*:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    // PRIVATE
    var _sendRequest = function(callback) {
        // send request and get response
        callback(response);
    };

    // PUBLIC
    var getInfo = function() {
        _sendRequest(function(response) {
            console.log("Response: ", response);
        );
    }

    return {
        getInfo: getInfo
    };
})();
```

As you can see, only `getInfo` is publicly accessible. `_sendRequest` is hidden away for private usage.

What I'm trying to do is put the `_sendRequest` method in a separate file while still keeping it private to the outside. I only want `getInfo` to be publicly accessible.

Is there a way to do this with the Module Pattern design, or should I think about switching design patterns? I've looked into Augmented Module Patterns, but they don't seem to keep methods like `_sendRequest` private as they should be. *I just want to store all my private utilities in a separate file while maintaining their private state.* Is this possible?

Comment: No it isnt. But you could trust other people at your server to know about the *underscore means private => dont use it if you havent wrote it*

Comment: Nothing straight forward jumps at me. You will still have to export _sendRequest if you move it to a separate file which means it's still possible to source dive and import it anyway

Comment: It would be possible if you move getInfo to it too ( and all other dependencies)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm just a little confused because a lot of the prominent JS libraries are obviously composed of many, many source files. Does this mean that, when using one of these libraries, I technically have access to many methods that weren't intended for public use?